# Changing background color of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, drop-down-menu

Could someone tell me how to change the background color of dropdownlist in vb.net visual studio 2012? I have the following code.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Drawing

<DefaultProperty("DataTable"), _
 ToolboxData("<{0}:DataDropDownList  runat=server></{0}:DataDropDownList>")> _
Public Class DataDropDownList
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
    DataDropDownList.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a css style for this DataDropDownList, What do you think of it?

Comment: that could work, but I'm just trying to change a property to check if the server control works

Comment: I see, it was to work (DataDropDownList.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson) in C#, but, maybe in vb is different.